# Best Approach for migrating data from Access to SQL Server in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Please Let me know if any best approach available for these two SSIS Activities.

1. migrating access data to SQL Server table

   multiple Access dbs are used as a source to migrate the data into a SQL table.
2. SQL server table to SQL server table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a one time job that should it be done periodically?

If one time job, then you can use SQL server Import Data utility to accomplish both things easily.

If it is just copy of data from source to destination without any modification to data, then there is no need to use SSIS.

Comment: Thanks Ajay. first one is one time process, and second one is daily running job. I guess First case can be suitable for the Sql server import data utility. In second case if we are going to package what can be the ideal way whether normal data flow can be used or any other method that can be used to improve the performance. And also it requires modification of data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. As JYousef has mentioned, first use SQL Server Import export wizard and configure the source, destination connections as well.              2. In Source, Destination Dialog of the wizard, you have option to edit mappings i.e, you can change the datatypes and the lengths.   3. Finally, uncheck "Run immediately" option and check "Save" option and click finish. You will have a basic package for porting data.       4. Open the package and use transformations in the data flow task to modify the data as per your need. Performance will be good since SQL to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL server Import and export wizard, at the end don't click on run now, and save the package , you can schedule these packages to do the same for you,

Yes you can copy from access to SQL table, and from SQL table to SQL table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=sql.105%29.aspx